# TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U8') dtype('<U8') dtype('<U8')

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble subtracting two columns of a data table, I am new to python and after failing in trying to research how to solve this issue I was wondering if anyone had any insight. My code is as such:

```
response = qc.query(token, sql=query, fmt='pandas')
result = Table.from_pandas(response)
g_r   =result['dered_mag_g'] - result['dered_mag_r']
r_z   = result['dered_mag_r'] - result['dered_mag_z']
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-836ed65f38bb> in <module>()
----> 1 g_r   =result['dered_mag_g'] - result['dered_mag_r']
      2 r_z   = result['dered_mag_r'] - result['dered_mag_z']
/data0/sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in __sub__(self, other)
   4083         if self._delegate_binop(other):
   4084             return NotImplemented
-> 4085         return subtract(self, other)
   4086
   4087     def __rsub__(self, other):
/data0/sw/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in __call__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs)
   1016         with np.errstate():
   1017             np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
-> 1018             result = self.f(da, db, *args, **kwargs)
   1019         # Get the mask for the result
   1020         (ma, mb) = (getmask(a), getmask(b))

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S8') dtype('S8') dtype('S8')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the dtypes are strings, try to apply astype():

```
g_r=result['dered_mag_g'].astype(float) - result['dered_mag_r'].astype(float)
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion for the code but now I get a new error:  `TypeError: Cannot convert fill_value N/A to dtype float64 `

Comment: Please, show a part of the table. Maybe you can apply result.replace("N/A",0)